# Query on ADLS Gen2 parquet using Synapse ServerLess SQL pool from C#

Tags: c#, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

Scenario:
I have a parquet file on ADLS Gen2, and is able to query via Synapse Serverless Pool.
I want to use Synapse Serverless pool in C# and execute the query and show result in my c# app.

Something like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string col1; 
           string connString = @" con string for synapse serverlesspool";
           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
           try
           {
                conn.Open();
                string query = @"SELECT      TOP (10) col1  
                                FROM OPENROWSET(
                                        BULK 'https:adlsgen2 path/file.parquet',
                                        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
                                    ) AS [result]
                                ";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            col1= dr.GetString(0);
                             Console.WriteLine("{0}", col1);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("No data found.");
                    }
                    dr.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
```

But when I execute it from C#, it says access denied on the parquet file.

> Error: Cannot find the CREDENTIAL 'https:adlsgen2 path/file.parquet',
> because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I know my Synapse can access the gen2folder, how do I make my C# app access the folder and query in C# via Synapse Serverless pool.

Thanks